# Controlling function inline-ability on a per invocation basis

Tags: c++, inline

I'm writing C++ library for embedded usage, so it must be 1) efficient; 2) as "efficient" cannot be reduced to static set of constraints, let programmer control code speed vs size tradeoffs on case by case basis. To cover this need, I consider letting programmer control inline-ability of large subset of methods. I could think of following pattern:

```
class Foo {
  ALWAY_INLINE void foo_i() { ... }
  NEVER_INLINE void foo_ni() { foo_i(); }
#if DEFAULT_INLINE
  ALWAY_INLINE void foo() { foo_i(); }
#else
  NEVER_INLINE void foo() { foo_i(); }
#endif
}
```

Here, ALWAY_INLINE/NEVER_INLINE are defines for compiler-specific attributes (I'm happy to target just gcc). And this scheme gives 3 versions of a method: one which will be always inlined, one which will be never inlined, and a "main" method with "default" inlinability (based on my decision as a library author).

Now, I'm not 100% sure about such scheme, specifically about _i/_ni suffixes and verboseness (the latter could be taken care of with macros, but that can lead to even more obscurity than suffixes).

I wonder, if there's any kind of best practices to handle such metaprogramming issue in C++, or at least existing examples how this is handled in other libs?

Please note that "let compiler control inlinability" is not an acceptable answer - the talk is exactly about controlling it explicitly.

Comment: let compiler control inlinability.

Comment: Rather than have 3 different names, why not have just one templated name? Much cleaner IMHO.

Comment: @syam: Can you elaborate? I'd be looking for something like "foo<inline>(); foo<no_inline>();" if C++ was "real" metaprogramming language. Alas. But maybe you have some ideas.

Comment: @pfalcon: Yes that's what I have in mind too. But I don't know how to implement it yet, because I'm not sure if you can specify different attributes for different specializations (and on top of that, templates are more likely to be inline than not). This is not an easy problem... (otherwise I'd have posted an answer not a comment xD) For now the only sure way I can see is to keep your weird naming scheme as a private API (just the ALWAYS/NEVER parts, mind you) and add a template around that, if only for syntactic sugarness.